# Error al mandar un archivo por sockets,no pude abrir el archivo[problema con codificacion]

Tags: python, python-3.x, socket

Estoy realizando un script en python que permite enviar archivos mediante la tecnología sockets, en este caso estoy enviando un archivo.pdf a otra maquina.

PROBLEMA:
Al recibir el archivo en la otra maquina no pude abrirlo; he utilizado nitroPDF y no habré después al intentar abrirlo con Word2016 sale el memsaje `Seleccione codificacion con la que desea leer el documento:`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo:

CLIENTE.PY

```
from socket import socket

def main():
    s = socket()
    s.connect(("192.168.8.2",8081))

    while True:
        f = open("uno.pdf","rb")
        content = f.read(1024)

        while content:
            s.send(content)
            content = f.read(1024)
        break
    try:
        s.send(chr(1))
    except TypeError:
        s.send(bytes(chr(1),"utf-8"))
    s.close()
    f.close()
    print("el archivo ha sido enviado")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

SERVIDOR.PY

```
from socket import socket,error

def main():
    s = socket()

    s.bind(("0.0.0.0",8081))
    s.listen(0)

    conn,addr = s.accept()
    f = open("recibido.pdf","wb")

    while True:
        try:
            input_data = conn.recv(1024)
        except error:
            print("error de lectura")
            break
        else:
            if input_data:
                if isinstance(input_data,bytes):
                    end = input_data[0]==1
                else:
                    end = input_data == chr(1)
                if not end:
                    f.write(input_data)
                else:
                    break
    f.close()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: ¿Por qué envías un byte de valor 1 después de haber enviado el fichero? ¿Pretendes usar ese valor "especial" como marca para que cuando el cliente lo reciba deje de escribir? En ese caso ahí tienes el problema, ya que un byte de valor 1 perfectamente podría aparecer en el flujo de bytes que es el propio fichero PDF. Si abortas la comunicación al recibir un 1, acabarás con un pdf incompleto y por tanto corrupto.

Comment: No necesitas enviar caracteres especiales para marcar el final. Cuando el cliente haya terminado de enviar todo el fichero, basta que cierre el socket. El servidor iterará sobre lo que reciba hasta que `len(input_data)==0`, pues esa es la condición que indica que el socket ha sido cerrado

Comment: El problema por tanto no tiene qué ver con la codificación. El hecho de que Word te pida la codificación del fichero es porque estás intentando abrir con Word un pdf corrupto, y al no saber cómo tratarlo asume que es un archivo de texto plano, para lo cual necesita saber además su _encoding_ para poder mostrarte los caracteres (lo que mostraría en todo caso no sería el pdf, sino los bytes que lo componen)

Comment: @abulafia, entonces debe de quedar asi `try:
        s.send()`

Comment: @abulafia, de lado del cliente solamente, me ayudarias si pudieras darme un ejemploo por favor

Comment: Un `s.send()` no funcionará, porque a `send()` siempre hay que pasarle algo. Quizás te he confundido al decirte que el servidor detectará el fin de la transmisión cuando no reciba nada. Eso es así, pero no significa que el cliente tenga que hacer un envío de "nada". Eso ocurrirá automáticamente cuando el cliente haga `s.close()`. El protocolo TCP hará su protocolo de cierre de conexión y el `recv()` del servidor retornará una cadena vacía. Mira la solución en mi respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te decía en un comentario, el cliente no debe enviar ningún byte extra una vez ha terminado de leer el fichero, sino simplemente cerrar el socket. Pero más importante aún *el servidor no debe dejar de leer cuando reciba un byte de valor 1*, pues ese podría formar parte del fichero que está recibiendo, en cuyo caso el PDF escrito en disco quedaría incompleto y por tanto corrupto. No es un problema de *codificación*, como pones en el título, sino de error de implementación que causa una comunicación incompleta.

Aparte de esto, tu cliente tiene una estructura un poco rara, que podría resumirse en:

```
while True:
   abrir_fichero
   enviar_fichero
   break
```

Y cabe preguntarse ¿qué papel juega ese `while True`? Realmente el bucle sólo se ejecutará una vez, puesto que una vez enviado el fichero haces `break` y eso abandona el bucle. Por tanto el bucle completo sobra y lo anterior podría igualmente ser:

```
abrir_fichero
enviar_fichero
```

Una vez el fichero se ha enviado, tenías una parte en la que transmitías un byte de valor 1. Eso sobra, y ya puedes directamente cerrar el socket.

Por tanto el **cliente** quedaría así:

```
from socket import socket

def main():
    s = socket()
    s.connect(("192.168.8.2",8081))

    f = open("uno.pdf","rb")
    content = f.read(1024)
    while content:
        s.send(content)
        content = f.read(1024)
    s.close()
    f.close()
    print("el archivo ha sido enviado")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Por su parte el **servidor** debe leer del socket de datos en bucle, hasta que lo que reciba sea una cadena de longitud cero. En ese caso habrá terminado la recepción del fichero. No necesitas todo eso de comparar con un byte de valor 1.

El servidor quedará así:

```
from socket import socket,error

def main():
    s = socket()

    s.bind(("0.0.0.0",8081))
    s.listen(0)

    conn,addr = s.accept()
    f = open("recibido.pdf","wb")
    while True:
        try:
            input_data = conn.recv(1024)
        except error:
            print("error de lectura")
            break
        if len(input_data) == 0:
            print("Recibido archivo completo")
            break
        f.write(input_data)

    conn.close()
    f.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```